# How to auto compute values from database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to auto compute the remaining stock from inventory by typing in the input type named used. What I want to happen is after I type a number in 'Withdrawn' it should subtract to quantity then show the result to remaining stock. The values came from the database.

Here's what I did but I didn't work I don't know why can you please help me? I am still a beginner btw so correct my code if it looks wrong. Thank you

list.php:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="updatebtnmodal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Update Used</h4>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                              
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form id="myForm" action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/inventory/updateused/'.$inv['i_id'];?>" method="POST"
                    class="form-container mx-auto  shadow-container" style="width:80%" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="update_id" id="update_id">
                                <label for="cname">Category</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control my-2 
                                <?php echo (form_error('name') != "") ? 'is-invalid' : '';?>" name="cname" id="cname"
                                    placeholder="Enter Item name" value="<?php echo set_value('cname',$inv['cat_id']); ?>" readonly>
                                <?php echo form_error('cname'); ?> 
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="update_id" id="update_id">
                                <label for="name">Item Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control my-2 
                                <?php echo (form_error('name') != "") ? 'is-invalid' : '';?>" name="name" id="name"
                                    placeholder="Enter Item name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" readonly>
                                <?php echo form_error('name'); ?> 
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="d_date">Delivered Date</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control my-2
                                <?php echo (form_error('d_date') != "") ? 'is-invalid' : '';?>" id="d_date" name="d_date"
                                    placeholder="Delivered Date" value="<?php echo set_value('d_date'); ?>"readonly>
                                <?php echo form_error('d_date'); ?>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="used">Withdrawn</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control my-2
                                <?php echo (form_error('used') != "") ? 'is-invalid' : '';?>" id="used" name="used" class="used" onchange="calc()"
                                    placeholder="Enter No. Withdrawn Items" value="<?php echo set_value('used'); ?>">
                                <?php echo form_error('used'); ?>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control my-2
                                <?php echo (form_error('quantity') != "") ? 'is-invalid' : '';?>" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="quantity"
                                    placeholder="Enter Quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity'); ?>">
                                <?php echo form_error('quantity'); ?>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exp_date">Expiration Date</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control my-2
                                <?php echo (form_error('e_date') != "") ? 'is-invalid' : '';?>" id="e_date" name="e_date" 
                                    placeholder="Expiration Date" value="<?php echo set_value('e_date'); ?>"readonly>
                                <?php echo form_error('e_date'); ?>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="rem_qty">Remaining Stock</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control my-2
                                <?php echo (form_error('rem_qty') != "") ? 'is-invalid' : '';?>" id="rem_qty" name="rem_qty" class="rem_qty"
                                    placeholder="Enter No. Remaining Stock" >
                                <?php echo form_error('rem_qty'); ?>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                </div>
                
                    <button type="submit" name="updatedata" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Make Changes</button>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/inventory/index'?>" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Js:

```
function calc() {
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML;
  var used = document.getElementById("used").value;
  var rem_qty = parseFloat(quantity) - used
  if (!isNaN(rem_qty))
    document.getElementById("rem_qty").innerHTML = rem_qty
}
```

Comment: Hi Josanu, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm having trouble understanding the language of your question. Could you please use the usual punctuation, like ending sentences with full stops, use quotes etc. Here on SO, it also helps to keep sentences as short as possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking in general. In particular, I do not understand this: "compute ... by typing in the input type named used." What should the user do and where, and how should the system react.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to do better next time. I apologize for my grammar, english is not my native language. anyway, I already fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this javascript code

```
function calc() {
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    var used = document.getElementById("used").value;
    
    var rem_qty = 0;
    if(quantity >= used){
        rem_qty = parseFloat(quantity) - used;
    }

    if(rem_qty != 0){
        document.getElementById("rem_qty").value = rem_qty
    }    
}
```

I hope this code will help you out.

Comment: Can i ask another question? your code worked but when I put more than 1 in used, the rem_qty stopped showing new result :(

Comment: can you more clarify your issue, i don't understand that

Comment: When I put greater than 1 number in the 'withdrawn' input type, it stops calculating

Comment: you can try to comment "if(quantity >= used)" this condition and also "if(rem_qty != 0)" this one, if the code works out its mean that your withdrawn number is greater than quantity